# Check if an email is already present within a collection in Firestore, with React Hooks and Context

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-context

I have been searching to find a solution for my use case but none of the previously found ones quite applies to me.

I have a EditorsContext where I want to receive a list of editors from a Firestore editors collection, and I want to check whether the user's email that is logging into the app is already present in the editors' and if not subscribe him with a default value.

My Context looks like this:

```
    export const EditorsContext = createContext();
    
    const EditorsProvider = (props) => {
      const [editors, setEditors] = useState([]);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getEditors = async () => {
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          const editors = await db
            .collection("editors")
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
                setEditors((arr) => [...arr, data]);
              });
            });
        };
        getEditors();
        setLoading(false);
    
      }, []);
...
```

And my Component looks like this:

```
    function MainScreen() {
      const { editors, loading } = useContext(EditorsContext);
      const [newEditor, setNewEditor] = useState([]);
    ...
      const CreateUserRoles = async () => {
        const currentUserEmail = await firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        const editorsEmails = await editors.map((editor) => editor.email);
        console.log("entered createUserRoles");
        console.log("current from the fucntion " + currentUserEmail);
        console.log("editors from the function " + editorsEmails);
    
        if (await editorsEmails.includes(currentUserEmail)) {
          console.log("the editor already exists");
        } else if ((await editorsEmails.length) <= 0) {
          console.log("there are no editors, collection will be initialized");
          const editorsRef = firebase.firestore().collection("editors");
          const editor = {
            email: currentUserEmail,
            role: "reviewer",
            lastSession: dateOutput,
          };
          await editorsRef.add(editor);
          await setNewEditor(newEditor);
          console.log("collection initiated successfully" + newEditor);
        } else {
          console.log("creating new editor");
          const editorsRef = firebase.firestore().collection("editors");
          const editor = {
            email: currentUserEmail,
            role: "reviewer",
            lastSession: dateOutput,
          };
          await editorsRef.add(editor);
          await setNewEditor(newEditor);
          console.log("editor added successfully" + newEditor);
        }
        
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading) {
          if (editors.lenght !== 0) {
            console.log("editors arrived");
            console.log(editors.length);
          } else {
            console.log("no editors yet. check the provider");
          }
        } else {
          console.log("loading");
        }
      }, [loading]);
....
```

I am quite sure that my issue is due to the useEffect triggering the function even if my editors array is empty (I try also with with: `if(editors.length !== 0)`). Anyone has any idea or solutions for this?
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is your error?

Comment: the problem I have is that, since my editors array arrives empty at first, my function gets triggered and the second condition (editorsEmails.length <= 0) is always true, so I end up with many editors with the same email.

Comment: you have a typo in ` if (editors.lenght !== 0)`.  length is mispelled.

Comment: and you may also need to add `editors` to your `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the same outcome, but thanks for pointing out the typos, was definitely sitting on this for too long :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `editors` to your useEffect array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      if (editors.length !== 0) {
        console.log("editors arrived");
        console.log(editors.length);
      } else {
        console.log("no editors yet. check the provider");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("loading");
    }
  }, [loading, editors]);
```

Comment: Yes I also gave this a go, but I keep getting duplicated since on the first render editors <= 0, I would think this is has to do with my loading condition but I can't see what I am doing wrong